# Assign admin module to all admin pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, administrator

Id like to assign an administrator module to all pages, This is very simple with site modules as you can assign in the "menu manager" tab , however in the admin module the "menu manager" tab is not available , any help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your module to position, which is used in every page. For example: `menu`, `bottom`, `footer`.

Isis possible module positions are (according to `templateDetails.xml`):

- menu
- submenu
- toolbar
- title
- status
- icon
- cp_shell
- cpanel
- bottom
- footer
- login
- debug

Try and see which fits you best.

Comment: Acctually i just found out that setting the module access to `public` does the trick

Comment: Interesting. What was access level before? So you don't have special access level youself?

Comment: Also just found out that setting to access `special` also does the trick , should this be a bug ? my v is 3.4.1

Comment: What acces level module had if you had issue? Can you replicate issue again?